# Angles at vertices made by intersection of plane and equilateral prism

Tags: trigonometry

An equilateral triangular prism cuts $x-y$ plane forming triangle $ABC$ whose vertices $ A(\alpha_1,\alpha_2),B(\beta_1,\beta_2),C(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) $ make angle pairs on prism sides as indicated in parantheses.

Find a trigonometric relation between the six angles.

EDIT1:

*Self Answer*

A development of the prism is added below.

$\alpha_1+\beta_1 =\pi,$ by Euclid's parallel lines (cut by transversal, internal angles sum $\pi$) thm. Considering all three faces

$$ \alpha_1+\beta_1+\alpha_2+\beta_2+\alpha_3+\beta_3 =3\pi $$

Alternately, considering sum of all external angles in a convex polygon $ABCA=2 \pi$ to which, due to one re-entrant vertex, we need to add another $\pi$ so that this angle sum $ \Sigma \psi_i= 3 \pi$ in the common tangent plane.

[image: Prism Intersection on Plane]

Comment: A picture would really help.

Comment: Hope the rough sketch clarifies what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) to calculate the dihedral angles of the prism (all of which are $\pi/3$) in terms of the plane angles at $A$, $B$, $C$:

$$\frac12=\cos\frac{\pi}{3} 
= \frac{\cos A-\cos\alpha_1\cos\alpha_2}{\sin\alpha_1\sin\alpha_2} 
= \frac{\cos B-\cos\beta_1\cos\beta_2}{\sin\beta_1\sin\beta_2} 
= \frac{\cos C-\cos\gamma_1\cos\gamma_2}{\sin\gamma_1\sin\gamma_2} \tag{1}$$
so that
$$\cos A = \frac12\sin\alpha_1 \sin\alpha_2 + \cos\alpha_1 \cos\alpha_2, \quad\text{etc} \tag{2}$$

Since $A+B+C=\pi$, we know
$$1 - \cos^2 A - \cos^2B - \cos^2C - 2 \cos A \cos B \cos C = 0 \tag{3}$$

Substituting from $(2)$ into $(3)$ gives a relation in the $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$, $\gamma_i$. I haven't found a "simple" representation of that relation, however, so I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. $\square$

Comment: Would   $\dfrac12 
= \frac{(\cos A+\cos B + \cos C) -(\cos\alpha_1\cos\alpha_2 +..+..) }
{\sin\alpha_1\sin\alpha_2+.. + .. } $ simplify?

Comment: @Narasimham: I don't think so.

Comment: Can you please sketch where  the sphere is, and how the prism intersects the sphere? Does the sphere radius tend to $\infty$ in a limit?

Comment: The sphere from the spherical law of cosines is a unit sphere centered at vertex $A$ (or $B$ or $C$). The planes meeting at that vertex cut a triangle in the sphere's surface; the lengths of the triangle's sides are exactly the (radian) measures of the face angles ($A$, $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$), while the triangle's angles match the dihedral angles formed by those planes. Spherical trig's laws of cosines allow one to determine sides from angles, and angles from sides, but all that matters here is that we can get dihedral angles from faces angles and vice-versa. The sphere itself is irrelevant.

Comment: Am unable to visualize it properly As far as I can understand when a triagular prism cuts a sphere we can have intersections generally not all three of them as great cicles. (Two great circles if an edge of prism passes through sphere center and one great circle if an edge passes through center). Can you please include  a sketch?

Comment: @Narasimham: The sphere is unrelated to the *prism*, just its *corners*. In 2D, we center a circle where two rays meet, and those rays hit the circle to determine an arc. In 3D, we center a sphere where three planes meet; the planes hit the sphere in great-circular arcs that form what happens to be a spherical triangle, whose edges and angles are directly related to the face- and dihedral-angles formed by the planes. 3D sketches are hard, so I'll refer you to the law of cosines link; imagine that the vertices of the triangle shown are connected to the sphere's center, making a 3D corner there.

Comment: @Narasimham: Ignore the prism. Just draw three planes that meet at the center of the sphere, and look at how these planes cut the sphere. (Comments really aren't the best place to explain all of this, and I don't seem to be doing a very good job of explaining it to you. Perhaps you should post a separate question specifically about how the spherical law of cosines relates to the face and dihedral angles formed by three concurrent planes.)

Comment: The second part of the comment needs no explanation, thinking about need for spherical trigonometry. at all I had an answer,.too simple that is ..

Comment: To apply the Cosine Rule in spherical trigonometry, the three sides of a spherical triangle should necessarily be geodesics or segments of great circles. In the present situation we have in general three circles of constant geodesic curvature κg; for example like parallel circles of a sphere. Derivation is not valid due to premises violation... It appears to me so. Please show at first how the three lines enclosing $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2, A )$are great circles. What follows could come later when needed.

Comment: I try to prepare a rough sketch later.

Comment: @Narasimham: Center a sphere at $A$. Plane $ABC$ passes through the center, meeting the sphere in a great circle; likewise for planes $ABD$ & $ACD$ (where $D$ is some point on the "vertical" edge through $A$). Thus, the trihedral "corner" formed by three concurrent planes corresponds to a geodesic triangle on the sphere. Assuming radius $1$, the triangle's side-lengths are $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $A$. Each triangle angle is measured via tangent vectors at a vertex, nicely matching the *dihedral* angles made by the planes. The LOC, then, simply relates a corner's plane angles to its dihedrals.

Comment: @Narasimham: I see your new sketch, and I also see that I'm still failing to make myself clear. Again: **Ignore the prism!(!!!)** The spherical Law of Cosines applies "locally", involving only particular vertex and the planes that concur at it. (The "trihedral corner".) To visualize it, make your sphere much smaller (or make your prism much larger), and then revisit all of my previous comments.

Comment: I shall continue in the effort to improve my comprehension. ; meanwhile adding another approach leading to an answer to my question.